# PayPal responsive checkout?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to show responsive PayPal checkout page to customers.

Link I'm using: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=
What I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDlWy.png

**I need to show mobile friendly responsive PayPal checkout page.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first link is an Adaptive Payments checkout. Adaptive Payments is a very old, deprecated PayPal product, and will not offer a responsive page.

To have a responsive page, switch to a normal PayPal checkout.

- Here is a front-end that depends on calling a server for setting up a v2/order and capturing that v2/order via API: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server  (notice the calls to '/demo/...' placeholders, which must be replaced with actual routes on your server).
- Here is a front-end that does not do that, and uses HTML/JavaScript only: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: Thanks for the response @Preston PHX. If so, do you have any idea how we can do split/parallel transactions in PayPal.

Comment: Classic EC parallel payments is also deprecated, but might possibly give a more responsive page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ht-ec-parallelPayments/ .  With EC parallel, the sender will always see each recipient they are paying in the checkout. I do not recommend using this, but it's the only publicly documented PayPal solution I'm aware of that does not require any approval (Approval for Adaptive Payments is no longer given, it's fully deprecated for new integrations)

Comment: You might be able to receive a single payment and do something with PayPal Payouts, if your business account is approved for that: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts

Comment: If you have reference transactions (another thing that requires approval), you could have a billing agreement on file with each other recipient, and they receive a single payment, and then you bill them correspondingly or in some batch cycle using reference transactions.